# Really slow WordPress site

Tags: php

I am almost done creating a website running with WordPress and WooCommerce. Unfortunately, the site is loading really, really slow. Loading a page easily takes 8-10 seconds.

I have 33 WordPress plugins running on the site, and at first I thought that one of these was the problem. After having disabled everything and then enabled one at the time, it is clear that it isn't one particular plugin causing the problems. The load time just becomes a little longer for each plugin being enabled, and ends with the 8-10 seconds.

I have tried using W3 total cache, and cdn from CloudFlare which doesn't change much. Also, I thought the server might be the problem, but I have earlier been involved with another website that runs on the same server, which runs really smooth, even though it is a forum with some 2000 users.

The theme used is Aware, with some changes
http://themeforest.net/item/aware-responsive-wordpress-portfolio-theme/1049029

Any ideas to make the site load faster would be really, really appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what can really be said looking from the side, but "use less plugins and/or faster server". If nothing in particular is detectably slow (which you say you looked for and didn't find) either you are using _very_ heavy functionality all over or your server/configuration is _very_ underpowered for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you also tried a default theme? I do not really believe that the theme is causing this, but trying doesn't hurt.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference :-/

Comment: Have you checked the site on a different server/local install. I had a WordPress site that was painfully slow on shared hosting. Turned out one of the other users on the server was hogging a lot of the resources.

Comment: Query Monitor. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing a [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140707_B5_1JC/1/details/) of your site, it looks like you're loading a lot of different JavaScript and CSS files. I would really recommend to minify and combine your JavaScript and CSS. You can use CloudFlare (which I highly recommend), W3 Total Cache, or [WP Minify Fix](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-minify-fix/). Be careful though, often times minification can break your site. Test it out and see if it helps to resolve things, as it cuts down your separate requests, which helps lower your site loading time.

Also, using the CloudFlare "Rocket Loader" (a general-purpose asynchronous JavaScript loader,) might also provide some performance improvements to your site, as it would allow your JavaScript to load after window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to get rid of the plugins you don't want. 
Next go to http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ and check which components are responsible for the slow loading. Once you have this data you can decide upon your next steps.

If possible, share you website link so we can guide you better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The site url is http://clevercoffee.dk I have tried the suggested link, and it seems like a lot of things are taking a lot of time. Can you figure out anything from the link? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find out what exactly slow down your site, here are some recommended plugins:

- P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)
- Debug Bar Slow Actions
- Query Monitor

Finally you can try to speed up your site using the [Speed Boster Pack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/speed-booster-pack/) plugin.